# A quiz which requires a user to register and sign in: python

Tags: python-2.7

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out how to allow a user to first register and then sign in to take a quiz. I’m finding it difficult as the users details such as name, age and year group as well as username and password need to be saved to a text file. I have some of the code for registration already completed but I'm still confused.

```
with open("user account .txt","w") as userFile:
    usernamePart1 = raw_input("Enter your name:")
    while not usernamePart1.isalpha():
        print("Invalid name, try again")
        usernamePart1 = raw_input("Enter your name:")
    usernamePart2 = raw_input("Enter your age:")
    while not usernamePart2.isdigit():
        print("try again") 
        usernamePart2 = raw_input("Enter your age:")
    fullUsername = usernamePart1[:3] + usernamePart2
    userFile.write("Username:" + fullUsername)
with open("reports.txt","a") as reports:
    reports.write("\n" + "Username:" + fullUsername)
    print "Your username is" + " " + (fullUsername)


UserYearGroup = int(raw_input("Enter your year group:"))
while UserYearGroup < 7 or UserYearGroup > 15:
    print("Invalid year group, enter again")
    UserYearGroup = int(raw_input("Enter your year group:"))
if UserYearGroup >= 7 and UserYearGroup <= 14:
    userFile.write("\nYear Group:" + str(UserYearGroup))
    print(UserYearGroup)


password = raw_input("Enter a password which you will remember:")
userFile.write("\nPassword:" + password)
```

It keeps saying this when i run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 22, in <module>
    userFile.write("\nYear Group:" + str(UserYearGroup))
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: which line is line 22 here ?

Comment: userFile.write(“\nYear Group:” + str(UserYearGroup))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code 
`userFile.write(“\nYear Group:” + str(UserYearGroup))` is not in the `with` block that defines `userFile` (the first `with block`).

As soon as you go out of the with block, the file is closed, and you cannot write to it.

You can :

- Make sure that all the code until this line is still in the `with` block defining `userFile`

for instance :

```
       with open("user account .txt","w") as userFile:
            usernamePart1 = raw_input("Enter your name:")
            while not usernamePart1.isalpha():
                print("Invalid name, try again")
                usernamePart1 = raw_input("Enter your name:")
            usernamePart2 = raw_input("Enter your age:")
            while not usernamePart2.isdigit():
                print("try again") 
                usernamePart2 = raw_input("Enter your age:")
            fullUsername = usernamePart1[:3] + usernamePart2
            userFile.write("Username:" + fullUsername)

            with open("reports.txt","a") as reports:
                reports.write("\n" + "Username:" + fullUsername)
                print "Your username is" + " " + (fullUsername)


            UserYearGroup = int(raw_input("Enter your year group:"))
            while UserYearGroup < 7 or UserYearGroup > 15:
                print("Invalid year group, enter again")
                UserYearGroup = int(raw_input("Enter your year group:"))
            if UserYearGroup >= 7 and UserYearGroup <= 14:
                userFile.write("\nYear Group:" + str(UserYearGroup))
                print(UserYearGroup)


            password = raw_input("Enter a password which you will remember:")
            userFile.write("\nPassword:" + password)
```

Or

- Add another `with open("user account .txt","w") as userFile:` to wrap your other writes.

Comment: I tried your amendment and it worked so thank-you. The next step I must program is if the user has already created an account and wishes to sign in.  First this piece of code at the start:                                                                                                            start = raw_input("Do you need to register or sign in?")                                                                                                            if start == "register" or start == "Register" :

Comment: And then after the code you fixed above:                                                 elif start == "sign in":                                                                                                              userEntry = raw_input("Please enter your username")                                                                                                 I'm not sure what to do after this though. Also sorry about the code as it wouldn't let me indent.

Comment: (You cannot indent in Stack Overflow comments, but you can use backticks ``` to at least do some code formatting inline) `like that`

Comment: @Coder_2842 . The core of your precise problem was that, to be able to edit your file, it must be *opened*, and the file will be opened as long at it is *inside the `with` block* . Do you understand what I mean with 'block' ?

Comment: Yes I do. Oh Thankyou

Comment: I just do not understand how to code the sign in section. I have saved their details to a text file when they register but do not know how to check if they firstly exist and then if their password is correct. Again, thank-you.

Comment: @Coder_2842 I think that is another question entirely. Stack Overflow encourages simple precise questions that can have a clear answer. You can simply write a new question, and feel free to copy the link to your new question in the comments on this one. I might or might not answer the new question myself, depends on my free time. Also, I recommend that you write some example of what your file looks like after they register.

Comment: Okay Thankyou very much for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48359369/a-quiz-which-allows-a-user-to-choose-when-they-want-to-register-or-sign-in